# Method for selecting points from a dataset with known distribution A, so the selected points have known distribution B

Tags: distributions, density-function

I have a dataset (10K points) that was sampled from distribution A (the pdf of distribution A is known).
I want to select a subset of the data (1k points), so the selected points have distribution B (the pdf of B is also known).
How would I do that?

Comment: $$B=F_B^{-1}(F_A(A))$$

Comment: Does this mean I can do something like this: np.random.choice(data_A, size=1000, replace=False, p=pdf_B(data_A)/pdf_A(data_A) )?

Comment: $F^{-1}$ is not $1/F$...

Comment: @Xi'an How that first formula produces a *subset* of $A$ is unclear.  Adam: yes.  That's the Radon-Nikodym derivative.  There may be tiny problems due to sampling without replacement, but the subset is small enough to avoid that.  There will be huge problems if any of the denominator values are undefined: you need to be sure the support of $B$ is a subset of the support of $A.$ Here's an `R` example: `A <- rnorm(1e4);
p <- dnorm(A, 1) / dnorm(A); p <- p / sum(p);
B <- sample(A, 1e3, replace=FALSE, prob=p)`